# What is the difference between <uses-feature> and <uses-library>?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I've gone through the android documentation to understand about what  and  mean by,

[< uses-library>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element)

[< uses-feature>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element)

But it's unclear finally what exactly is the difference between both. Though it's a library it can be described as a feature as well. What's the use of both and when to use which one if we are creating a library or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) :

uses-feature:

> The  element allows you to declare hardware and software features your app needs. For example, if your app cannot achieve basic functionality on a device without a compass sensor, you can declare the compass sensor as required with the following manifest tag:
>   
>       
>       ...

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
              android:required="true" />
...</manifest>
```

uses-library:

> Specifies a shared library that the application must be linked against.

Comment: But still if my app needs maps library to render some component - from maps application perspective it's more like a feature which i'm offering. From my application perspective it's a library i'm consuming. I'm getting confused here.

Comment: feature is just a word here I am not sure but incase of maps you are not integrating the whole maps sdk with you app but you are relying that the system on which this app will install will have that library that you app needs. If not the google play store can simply filter out you app to be displayed to that user